# ORM Mapping inheritance with two strategies at once in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, orm

Now, as far as I know, there are two most used inheritance mapping strategies in JPA:

1. **Single table** - where all the classes (both subclasses and superclasses) are mapped in a single table that has as columns all the fields from all the classes; and the fields specific only to some subclasses are NULL in other corresponding entries.

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="types")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="types", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=1)
public abstract class Base { //... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="A")
public class TypeA extends Base { //... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="B")
public class TypeB extends Base { //... }
```

1. **Joined table strategy** - where there is one table for the base class having as columns all the base class' fields and one other column for type; also there are specific tables for each subclass each having only the corresponding subclass' fields which are mapped one-to-one (by PK) with the base table.

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="types",discriminatorType=STRING, length=1)
public abstract class Base { //... }

@Entity
@Table(name="SELLERS")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="A")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="base_id")
public class TypeA extends User { //... }

@Entity
@Table(name="BIDDERS")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="base_id")
public class TypeB extends User { //... }
```

In my domain I have these classes:

```
public abstract class Base {
//data
}

public class TypeA extends Base {
//only one field
}

public class TypeB extends Base {
// many more fields
}
```

and I would want a 1. inheritance mapping strategy between TypeA and Base and 2. inheritance mapping strategy between TypeB and Base (this is an oversimplification; there are actually many entities) because I wouldn't want another table for one more field. Is this possible in JPA and does it make any sense?

Edit: I do not know what is wrong with the code formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible in JPA.  You need to configure `@Inheritance` at the base class level, and it can't be overridden at the subclass level.

Your options do however include one more possibility which you didn't mention, which is [`InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.0/apache-openjpa-1.0.0/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html#jpa_overview_mapping_inher_tpc).  If you use this, you'd have N tables (for N subclasses) rather than one or N+1.  And it works well for some cases, see the advantages/disadvantages in the link.

Comment: I know buy I do not find that good neither from an OO nor from a relational point of view.

Comment: Well, I don't necessarily recommend `TABLE_PER_CLASS` for you, just pointing it out as an option.  The [impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) between the database and the programming language is going to force some tradeoffs.  The ORM layer eases some of it, but no tool is going to cover all special cases, and yours is special: "I want a seperate table except in cases where it's only a couple of columns."